# Connect three different power sources

Tags: voltage, amplifier

If I connect between three power sources, first one: 220vac 700ma , the second and the third: 12vac 500ma, what is the voltage and current result (I need just increase the current) ???

The power sources will be connected as follows: A have two wires A1,A2..... B have two wires B1,B2...... C have two wires C1,C2...... if I connect A1+B1+C1 will be the first wire, and connect A2+B2+C2 will be the second wire, if I measure the two result wires how much voltage and current?

Comment: Hi! Welcome! Please provide the schematic to show how do you connect it. Also what do you mean by increasing the current? Please provide more details in your question.

Comment: If A produce 220vac 700ma , B produce 12vac 500ma , C produce 12vac 500ma, each one of A B and C have two wires, if I connect all wires with each others, what will the result of voltage and current

Comment: Again, please provide the schematic, we don't know what do you mean by connecting all the wires each others unless you provide the schematic.

Comment: **Never do this!**

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that this will not work. The power supplies will fight each other and something will probably burn out.

If you want to connect 2 power supplies together, they must be DC, and the same voltage. Even then there are complicating factors, such as: how do you get the supplies to share the load evenly?

Practically speaking, you should just get a single more powerful supply.

Comment: When I was in school I learned, that u can connect 2 batteries with each other I have two ways, ok , parallel and series, I can double the current with the same voltage, or double voltage with the same current ok, what if the two batter have different voltage and current what is the result, and if  just example that this battery AC , what will be the result, I just ask simple question

Comment: The answer is that the greater voltage battery will force charge into the lower voltage one and it will probably burst. Also there are no AC batteries.

Comment: 2 batteries that are the same voltage may be used in parallel.

Comment: Batteries and AC power sources are two very, *very* different things.  You can not combine AC sources the way you can with DC sources.  That is the simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

A battery with higher voltage will charge the other batteries/accumulators with lower voltage. This will raise the voltage at the other batteries. What exactly then happens depends on the chemistry of the involved batteries. However, this may not only destroy your batteries but be very dangerous for yourself and others!

Here is an excerpt from [itstillruns.com](https://itstillruns.com/happens-overcharge-car-battery-5137116.html) about overcharging a car battery:

> A battery can quite simply die from being overcharged. This is the safest side-effect, but not the only thing that can happen. An overcharged battery will boil the sulfuric acid and distilled water mix. The casing of the battery can become hot to the touch, and begin to melt or swell. Flammable hydrogen can build up inside the sealed cells of the battery, causing swelling of the casing under pressure and seepage through small vents. Once the hydrogen is introduced to oxygen, it becomes a sitting time bomb. A small electrical spark can ignite the gas and cause the battery to explode, sending plastic and lead shrapnel flying around, in addition to a caustic sulfuric acid spray. Obviously, this is the most dangerous side-effect of an overcharged battery.